# JPA locking database record

Tags: jpa

I am writing a spring boot service using JPA to interact with database. What I want to do is to lock down a database record as soon as it is read by JPA i.e. once is has been read no other thread will be able to read it until the first has updated the record.

Comment: Wonder what that `lock` method on `EntityManager` and `Query` is for ?

Comment: @BillyFrost those locks are different from what I am trying to do, they wouldn't stop a second thread to read the same record.